# Need help identifying this SoC

Tags: linux, arm

Does anybody know the manufacturer of this ARM CPU / SoC? I cannot find any information about it. I don't even know what the character in front of “Star” means.

“SAV500D” seems to be the model, the following lines seem to be serial numbers. I have two of them, only the first line is the same.

Thanks a lot for any help!

[image: soc]

Comment: The thing before the "Star" text just seems to be a simple logo; a star with a halo around it and some sort of flare at two o'clock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manufacturer appears to be http://sigmastarsemi.com

Also this site might be useful: http://linux-chenxing.org/

Comment: Their logo looks slightly different and the chips in their images look different, too.

Comment: Probably an older version of the logo  http://www.sigmastarsemi.com/uploadfile/image/20200603/20200603114546_56334.png

Comment: sigmastar is correct indeed. There is very little public information available about this chip. I'm trying to do some reverse engineering on this one, with me luck ;)